# Different type of series in highstock with json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

In the example below, how to have:

- serie 'MSFT' in type line
- serie 'AAPL' in type column
- serie 'GOOG' in type spline

---

```
$.each(names, function (i, name) {

    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=' + name.toLowerCase() + '-c.json&callback=?',    function (data) {

        seriesOptions[i] = {
            name: name,
            data: data
        };

        // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
        // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
        seriesCounter += 1;

        if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
            createChart();
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/

Comment: this question doesn't make any sense? Please see [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a `types` array and use that in your loop function: http://jsfiddle.net/epaLtjre/

```
var seriesOptions = [],
    seriesCounter = 0,
    names = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GOOG'],
    types = ['line', 'column', 'spline']; // add types
```

And later:

```
        seriesOptions[i] = {
            name: name,
            data: data,
            type: types[i] // apply type to the series
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is to show combined charts, here is an example of this scheme.

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/combining-chart-types

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want to do this directly in the loop.